# How can I add a category list on left side of page?

Tags: magento2

I saw this category bar on left side of many magento 2 websites.

[image: category tree bar]

What are the requirements to display this? I do not see categories in the layered navigation at all.

[image: as I this website]

**EDIT** 
I added my categories like this .

[image: categories]

Comment: https://github.com/Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar - this extension might help you

Comment: yes i needed some thing like this . But I think its magento2 default widget somewhere ? @AbhishekPanchal

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal I added but just  "Category" is written on left side . what is issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have the 2 column layout option selected for the page design, and have valid categories created, you should see a categories area in that left section using Magento's default themes. If you are using a custom theme, that column may not exist for you.

Comment: I am using Ultimo theme

Comment: I did but why no category is showing

Comment: Are all of your created categories created as sub-categories of the default category? Or are they at the root level?

Comment: I updated question with categories images I added. @codestr

Comment: When you go to edit a category, under the 'Design Options' section, is 'Anchor' enabled?

Comment: In display option Anchor is enable . In design option there is not option I think ?

Comment: Sorry, Display Options was the one I was referring to. And the categories have visible/active products listed under them? They may not display if no products are available. Outside of those configuration options, I'm not sure what the issue could  be without knowing more about your theme.

Comment: it was my theme options which was stopping. can I ask another question aswell ?

Comment: Sure, I'll help if I can. It may benefit you more to create it as a new question though, incase I can't help.